# Validar teléfonos de Argentina con una expresión regular

Tags: php, regex, validación

Necesito verificar un formulario, y en este tengo un campo para ingresar números telefónicos.

Según [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_telef%C3%B3nicos_en_Argentina) los números telefónicos argentinos, cito:

> Los códigos de área pueden tener 2, 3 o 4 dígitos, siendo los 6, 7 u 8 dígitos restantes el número de teléfono local.
>
> Por ejemplo, el número `+54 11 1234-5678` de Buenos Aires está compuesto de un código de área de 2 dígitos seguido de un número de teléfono de ocho dígitos; mientras que `+54 341 123-4567` sería un ejemplo de un número de Rosario.

En resumen, necesitaría una expresión regular que abarque todos esos casos. Y necesitaría agregarle una regla, la cual sería que el `+54` sea opcional.

Por el momento estoy usando como última opción esta expresión:

```
/^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s\.-]?\d{4}[\s\.-]?\d{4}$/
```

pero no es lo que estoy buscando ya que este permite `(11) 1234 3434` o `1123243434`, etc. Necesitaría agregarle las reglas explicadas arriba por ejemplo `(353) 123 4345` y que el `+54` sea opcional

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Podemos elegir validar de 2 formas:

**1. Forma sencilla:** eliminar todo lo que no es un número.

La forma directa de comprobar si un número de teléfono argentino es válido consiste en eliminar del string todo lo que no sea un número y validar que tenga 10 dígitos (más los prefijos como opcionales).

```
/^(?:(?:00)?549?)?0?(?:11|[2368]\d)(?:(?=\d{0,2}15)\d{2})??\d{8}$/
```

- Toma como opcionales:

  - el prefijo internacional (54)
  - el prefijo internacional para celulares (9)
  - el prefijo de acceso a interurbanas (0)
  - el prefijo local para celulares (15)
- Es obligatorio:

  - el código de área (11, 2xx, 2xxx, 3xx, 3xxx, 6xx y 8xx)
    (no toma como válido un número local sin código de área como `4444-0000`)

Código:

```php
function tel_argentino_valido ( $tel ) {
    //eliminamos todo lo que no es dígito
    $num = preg_replace( '/\D+/', '', $tel);
    //devolver si coincidió con el regex
    return preg_match(
        '/^(?:(?:00)?549?)?0?(?:11|[2368]\d)(?:(?=\d{0,2}15)\d{2})??\d{8}$/D',
        $num
    );
}
```

---

#### 2. Analizar cada parte del número

Si en cambio nos interesa validar más exhaustivamente pero, al mismo tiempo, extraer cada una de las partes que forman el número, entonces vamos con un regex bastante más largo y más estricto:

```
/^(?:((?P<p1>(?:\( ?)?+)(?:\+|00)?(54)(?<p2>(?: ?\))?+)(?P<sep>(?:[-.]| (?:[-.] )?)?+)(?:(?&p1)(9)(?&p2)(?&sep))?|(?&p1)(0)(?&p2)(?&sep))?+(?&p1)(11|([23]\d{2}(\d)??|(?(-10)(?(-5)(?!)|[68]\d{2})|(?!))))(?&p2)(?&sep)(?(-5)|(?&p1)(15)(?&p2)(?&sep))?(?:([3-6])(?&sep)|([12789]))(\d(?(-5)|\d(?(-6)|\d)))(?&sep)(\d{4})|(1\d{2}|911))$/D
```

Que no te engañe el largo del regex: es básicamente una repetición de los separadores opcionales (paréntesis, espacios, guiones o puntos) verificando que estén en alguno de los formatos que normalmente usamos. El hecho de que sea un regex largo no lo hace menos eficiente.

Explicado con el diagrama de [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F4UsFiylh3lVpwau) (abrir la imagen en otra pestaña para ver al 100%):

[image: Diagrama del regex en Debuggex]

Características:

- Esta expresión está optimizada para PCRE (el motor de regex de PHP), y no es compatible con otros lenguajes (JavaScript, Java, .Net, Python, etc.). Si se quiere validar en JavaScript, se puede usar la forma sencilla (en el punto 1).
- Sigue tomando como opcionales los prefijos, y el código de área sigue siendo obligatorio.
- Prefijo internacional (opcional): `+54`, `0054` o `54`.
- Valida códigos de área:

  - `11` (+ 8 dígitos)
  - `2xx` y `3xx` (+ 7 dígitos), o `2xxx` y `3xxx` (+ 6 dígitos)
  - o números no geográficos: `06xx` y `08xx` (+ 7 dígitos, sólo si se usó el `0` o el `54`)
- Acepta el `15` de celulares luego del código de área (si no se usó `9` luego del código internacional).
- Permite los separadores:  , `-`, `.`,  `-`  y  `.`  (opcionales, pero sólo en los lugares válidos).

  - aunque también acepta un guión después de un 3, 4, 5 o 6 como primer dígito del número local, para tomar como válida la mala costumbre de separar como `11-4-333-0000`
- Permite encerrar en paréntesis a: código internacional, prefijo internacional para celulares, prefijo de acceso a interurbanas, código de área o prefijo local para celulares (todo opcional).
- También acepta números sociales (110, 114, 911, etc.), aunque se puede filtrar en el resultado si no se quieren.

La ventaja de esta expresión, es que nos permite usar grupos para devolver cada parte por separado. Es decir, que podemos tomar el resultado de la función como verdadero/falso, o asignarla a una variable y obtener cada parte del número por separado.

**Código**

```php
function tel_argentino($tel) {
    $re = '/^(?:((?P<p1>(?:\( ?)?+)(?:\+|00)?(54)(?<p2>(?: ?\))?+)(?P<sep>(?:[-.]| (?:[-.] )?)?+)(?:(?&p1)(9)(?&p2)(?&sep))?|(?&p1)(0)(?&p2)(?&sep))?+(?&p1)(11|([23]\d{2}(\d)??|(?(-10)(?(-5)(?!)|[68]\d{2})|(?!))))(?&p2)(?&sep)(?(-5)|(?&p1)(15)(?&p2)(?&sep))?(?:([3-6])(?&sep)|([12789]))(\d(?(-5)|\d(?(-6)|\d)))(?&sep)(\d{4})|(1\d{2}|911))$/D';
    if (preg_match($re,$tel,$match)) {
        //texto capturado por cada grupo -> variables individuales
        list(
            ,$internacional_completo,,$internacional,,,$internacional_celu,$prefijo_acceso,$area,,,
            $prefijo_celu,$local_1a,$local_1b,$local_1c,$local_2,$numero_social
        ) = array_pad($match,20,'');

        //arreglar un poco los valores
        $local_1 = $local_1a . $local_1b . $local_1c;
        $local = $local_1 . $local_2;
        $es_fijo = !($internacional_celu || $prefijo_celu);
        $numero = $area.$local.$numero_social;
        $completo = $internacional.$internacional_celu.$area.$prefijo_celu.$local.$numero_social;

        //devolver sólo lo que importa en un array
        return compact(
                   'numero','completo','internacional','internacional_celu','area',
                   'prefijo_celu','local','local_1','local_2','numero_social','es_fijo'
               );
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Ejemplo:**

```php
tel_argentino('(+54 9 261) 333-4444');
```

```php
array (
  'numero' => '2613334444',
  'completo' => '5492613334444',
  'internacional' => '54',
  'internacional_celu' => '9',
  'area' => '261',
  'prefijo_celu' => '',
  'local' => '3334444',
  'local_1' => '333',
  'local_2' => '4444',
  'numero_social' => '',
  'es_fijo' => false,
)
```

<sup>* Nota: si no se usaron separadores en el número, podría separar mal en `area` un código de área de 3 dígitos como por ejemplo `343` (Paraná), en vez de tomar el de 4 dígitos `3436` (Victoria). Pero ese `6` no se pierde, aparece como primer dígito de `local_1`, y en `numero` se obtiene el `3436xxyyyy`... Se crean nuevos códigos de área con el tiempo, y la única forma de separarlo correctamente sería comparando contra un [listado continuamente actualizado](http://datosabiertos.enacom.gob.ar/dashboards/20141/numeracion/). Sin embargo, para la mayoría de los casos de uso, no suele ser relevante separar bien ese dígito distinguiendo si es un código de área de 4 dígitos o parte del número local.</sup>

**Pruebas**

```
             PRUEBA ❔ NUMERO      AREA  L1  L2    FIJO?
   +54 11 4444-0000 ✔ 1144440000    11 4444 0000  sí
    +54 341 1118888 ✔ 3411118888   341  111 8888  sí
   (+549261)1234567 ✔ 2611234567   261  123 4567  no
     (0351)333-4444 ✔ 3513334444   351  333 4444  sí
   266 - 999 - 0000 ✔ 2669990000   266  999 0000  sí
        343-1238888 ✔ 3431238888   343  123 8888  sí
     +5491188884444 ✔ 1188884444    11 8888 4444  no
       543412228888 ✔ 3412228888   341  222 8888  sí
(54)233-15-111-2222 ✔ 2331112222   233  111 2222  no
   (+54-343)9990000 ✔ 3439990000   343  999 0000  sí
 +54 (3436) 99-0000 ✔ 3436990000  3436   99 0000  sí
      (0)8003337333 ✔ 8003337333   800  333 7333  sí
   +54 11(4444)0000 ✖                             
   +54 341 1111-888 ✖                             
   (+54261)12-34567 ✖                             
     (03510)3334444 ✖                             
        266-99-0000 ✖                             
          4444-5555 ✖                             
       34-5555-0000 ✖
```

[>>> Demo en Ideone](https://ideone.com/tGocUv) y en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0hcTpt/1)

---

**El regex explicado** (sólo para fanáticos)

```cpp
$re = '/
^ # Inicio del texto

(?:
  # PREFIJO INTERNACIONAL Y/O INTERURBANO (opcionales) - Grupo 1
  (
    # INTERNACIONAL
    # Grupo "p1" (abre paréntesis)
    #   este grupo lo defino acá y después lo llamo varias veces con (?&p1)
    #   El (?: ... )?+ hace que todo sea opcional
    #   `\(` coincide con la apertura de paréntesis
    #   ` ?` es un espacio opcional
    (?P<p1>(?:\( ?)?+)

    # Opcional: un `+` o un `00`
    #   `54` prefijo de Argentina
    (?:\+|00)?(54)

    # Grupo "p2" (cierra paréntesis)
    #   La estructura es idéntica a "p1" (leer ahí).
    #   También lo vamos a reutilizar después como (?&p2)
    (?<p2>(?: ?\))?+)

    # Grupo "sep" (separador)
    #   También lo vamos a reutilizar después como (?&sep)
    #   El (?: ... )?+ hace que todo esto sea opcional
    #   `[-.]` un guión o un punto, o
    #   ` (?:[-.] )?` un espacio, opcionalmente seguido por guión/punto y otro espacio
    (?P<sep>(?:[-.]| (?:[-.] )?)?+)


    # 9 PARA CELULARES (internacional) - Grupo 6
    #   El (?: ... )? que engloba a esto, hace que esta parte sea opcional
    #   (?&p1)  (?&p2)  y  (?&sep) son subrutinas (llamadas) al patrón definido
    #   en los grupos con esos nombres (p1, p2 y sep). Es exactamente lo mismo
    #   que si volviera a escribir esa parte. De esta forma, sólo defino una vez
    #   el patrón para abrir paréntesis, cerrarlo, y el separador. Pero cabe
    #   destacar que en cada uno de esos 3 grupos, todo es opcional, por lo que
    #   cuando los llamo, siguen siendo siempre opcionales.
    (?:(?&p1)(9)(?&p2)(?&sep))?

  |

    # 0 PARA INTERURBANO
    #   `0` (opcionalmente precedido por paréntesis, sucedido, y/o seguido de separador)
    (?&p1)(0)(?&p2)(?&sep)

  )?+      # <-- este `?+` hace que el prefijo internacional/interurbano sea opcional



  # CÓDIGO DE ÁREA: 
  (?&p1)
  (
    # Prefijo BsAs
    11
  |
    # Áreas 2, 3, 6 o 8 - Grupo 9
    (
      # Prefijos 2xx, 3xx, 2xxx o 3xxx
      # -usamos grupos (paréntesis) porque después vamos a preguntar si se utilizaron
      #  para determinar cuántos dígitos más faltan para llegar a 10 del total.
      #  Si tiene 4 dígitos el código de área, usa a `(\d)` - Grupo 10
      [23]\d{2}(\d)??
    |
      # Prefijos 6xx o 8xx
      #   esta estructura es un IF: (?(cond)true|false)
      #   condición `-10`: si se usó el grupo yendo para atrás 10 grupos, es decir
      #                    el grupo 1 (54 o 0)
      #   verdadero: un IF anidado
      #              condición `-5`: si se usó el grupo 6 (el 9 de celulares)
      #              verdadero: fallar! porque no puede tener un 9 en un 0800 o 0600
      #                         el `(?!)` es una estructura que no puede coincidir jamás
      #              falso: Ok, intenta coincidir con `[68]\d{2}`
      #   falso: `(?!)` también falla (tiene que tener código de área)
      (?(-10)(?(-5)(?!)|[68]\d{2})|(?!))
    )
  )
  (?&p2)
  (?&sep)

  # 15 PARA CELULARES (opcional)
  #   Es un IF, pero el `?` del final hace que todo esto sea opcional
  #   condición `-5`: si se usó el grupo 6 (el 9 de celulares)
  #   verdadero: nada, sigue sin intentar coincidir esta parte
  #   falso: intenta coincidir con un `15` (opcional paréntesis y separador)
  (?(-5)|(?&p1)(15)(?&p2)(?&sep))?

  # NÚMERO LOCAL
  #  Primer dígito
  (?:
    # si es un 3, 4, 5 o 6, permite un separador (opcional)
    #   (es para aceptar la mala costumbre de escribir algo
    #   como `11-4-333-0000` de cuando se agregó el 10° dígito)
    ([3-6])(?&sep)
  |
    # sino, cualquier otro número menos el cero
    # (no acepta 0 como primer dígito del número local)
    ([12789])
  )
  #  Restantes 1-3 dígitos de la primera parte
  (
    # 1 dígito más (el 2do del número local)
    \d
    # IF condición: si se usó el grupo 10 (4 dígitos en código de área)
    # verdadero: nada, ya tiene los 2 dígitos locales, no puede tener más
    # falso: 1 dígito más seguido de un IF anidado
    #        condición: si se usó el grupo 9 (áreas 2, 3, 6 o 8)
    #        verdadero: nada, ya tiene los 3 dígitos locales
    #        falso: un dígito más (prefijo 11 => 4 locales)
    (?(-5)|\d(?(-6)|\d))
  )
  #  separador (opcional)
  (?&sep)
  #  Últimos 4 dígitos
  (\d{4})

|

  # NÚMERO SOCIAL (1xx o 911)
  (1\d{2}|911)
)

$ # Fin del texto

# Modificadores:
# [D] hace que $ sólo pueda coincidir al final (y no antes del último \n)
# [x] ignora espacios en blanco y comentarios. Hace que todo este string se pueda 
#     pasar así tal cual a preg_match() con varias líneas y comentarios
/Dx';
```

- Así como está, se puede usar en el código, si preferís tener el regex comentado.

---

Alternativas:

Yo prefiero este tipo de validaciones manuales para este caso, pero puede resultarte más sencillo utilizar alguna de estas soluciones:

- [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) de Google (Port a PHP: [libphonenumber for PHP](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php#libphonenumber-for-php--) - [demo](https://giggsey.com/libphonenumber/index.php)).
- [Twilio Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) (REST API que requiere que te registres -las consultas para validar y formatear son gratuitas) - [ejemplo de código](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups?code-sample=code-lookup-with-national-formatted-number&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x).
- [intl-tel-input](https://intl-tel-input.com/) para JavaScript (jQuery plugin con form validation que usa libphonenumber) - [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/intl-tel-input) - [tutorial](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-international-phone-numbers/)
- O podés bajarte el [listado completo de numeraciones asignadas](http://datosabiertos.enacom.gob.ar/dashboards/20141/numeracion/) de la web del ENACOM y comprobar que exista el indicativo y su bloque.

Comment: ... Y probablemente me pase un par de días editando la respuesta, intentando explicar ese regex :-/

Comment: No hay medalla de Platino para etiquetas?

Comment: Wow, quede sorprendido, te agradezco mucho. Voy a implementarlo para que funcione en mi proyecto, me gusto mucho la parte de separar en bloques el numero! Me va a servir muchísimo. Gracias

Comment: Alguna idea de como sería esta regex en javascript? gracias!

Comment: muy buen trabajo :) me va ayudar mucho