# Convertir PCRE (PHP) a una expresión regular que funcione en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, pcre

Tengo esta expresión regular en PCRE que obtengo desde esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136325/validar-tel%C3%A9fonos-de-argentina-con-una-expresi%C3%B3n-regular)

¿Como puedo pasarla a que funcione en javascript?

Comment: al principio de la respuesta está la que vale para javascript : "Si se quiere validar en JavaScript, se puede usar la forma sencilla (en el punto 1)."

Comment: Por favor, intenta utilizar la solución de "forma sencilla" de la pregunta que enlazas adaptándola para javascript. Si durante el proceso tienes algún problema *concreto* repórtalo para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Encontré una librería que hace mejor este trabajo y para todos los países https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js
Gracias a todos por sus comentarios