# como validar numero de telefono con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de validar números de teléfono, tengo un proyecto para un negocio, esta aplicación requiere registro con numero de celular, comúnmente en argentina los números son de esta forma, 11-32397240, necesito alguna expresión regular para poder validar esto, el 11 siempre se tiene que encontrar primero, solo son 10 números, encontre esto en la web

```
/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

pero este regex valida estos formatos,
(123) 456-7890
(123)456-7890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
1234567890
+31636363634
075-63546725

pero no es lo que busco, ayuda

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar que has intentado hacer? Mostrar código que has realizado, para poder brindarte ayuda.

Comment: agregando......

Comment: Fijate la opción **1** en [Validar teléfonos de Argentina con una expresión regular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136406/193460)